# What is the use for the argument block in anonymous functions

Tags: php, anonymous-function

In this example:

```
$foo = function () use (){
//     ^---------^ what is the use?

}
```

Aside this from being a function that we can use the `use ()` part to import a data into the function, just like a regular function as in:

```
function bar ($foo){

}
```

but I don't understand what the `function ()` part can be used for?

Comment: The question is not clear. `function` token is used to tell the parser it's a function. And parentheses after a `function` token are there to tell the parser "here is where parameters are defined"

Comment: @zerkms in this example: `function () use () {}` the `use()` part imports anything the function scope, which means, it is doing what a normal function is doing, but in that case, what about the first parenthesis? what is it used for? is it supposed to be empty?

Comment: Using an anonymous function as a callback for the various usorts requires function _parameters_ of the two values for comparison. The `use` is for _additional_ values. e.g. `usort($array, function($a, $b) { return strnatcmp($a, $b); });` and compare with `usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($key) { return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]); });`

Comment: @Contax "which means, it is doing what a normal function is doing" --- not at all.

Comment: You may have misunderstood the use of `use`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

e.g:

```
$a = 1;
$foo = function ($b, $c) use ($a)
{
    echo $a . PHP_EOL;
    echo $b . PHP_EOL;
    echo $c . PHP_EOL;
};

$foo(2, 3);
$a = 5;
$foo(7, 8);
```

Would output:

```
1
2
3
1
7
8
```

**$b, $c** - would be parameters you pass on execution.
**$a** is bound/imported on creation. So if you change it after $foo definition it would not change.

Comment: so the difference is that the function reads the params everytime it is called, but not the `use` key?

Comment: @Contax Something like that.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter block is for inputting parameters. So if I define

```
$foo = function($bar) use ($baz) {
    return $bar + $baz;
}
```

and then I, say, pass `$foo` to another function or bind it to another class, I can do like

```
function bonk($bar, $foo) {
  $baz = 4;
  return $foo($bar);
}
```

and somewhere else call

```
// Returns 7
bonk(3, $foo);
```

One allows you to get the variable from context while the other must be passed in. For example, I have $baz available to me in the class that defines $bonk so I pass it in, but I don't yet know what $bar is going to be until it bonk gets called somewhere else with $bar passed in.

So ok let's say I'm a class called Cats and I have an object SiameseCat available to me. I have a method called doTheThing that takes a function and a parameter. It tells the cat what to do and optionally what to do it to. So it always has the same cat but depending on where I call it from, I can have the siamese cat do different verbs to different nouns, but I know it's my cat doing it because that's where I defined the cat.

Comment: but if you wanted to compute `$bar + $baz` you could have passed both of them through `use ($bar, $baz)` so this still does no answer why we need the first parenthesis

Comment: '$bonk(3, $foo);' should be 'bonk(3, $foo);'